# EXCEL VBA - Skip line if it will error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the below query which basically resets the headeras of a table, and then resets a few slicers.

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Range("B12").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Return_Period").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Branch_Open").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Branch_RTN").ClearManualFilter
End Sub
```

If nothing has been selected in one of the tables the below line will error:

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

How can I skip this line if it will error, and just move on to clearing my slicers ?

Answer (score 0):

This was far easier than I had anticipated.

I was able to add in the line:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Which works similar to an IFERROR.

Full code now looks like:

```
Sub ClearAll()
On Error Resume Next
    Range("B12").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
On Error Goto 0
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Return_Period").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Branch_Open").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Branch_RTN").ClearManualFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner If you are ever in Birmingham UK I owe you a drink for all the help you have provided since I joined SU !